# Resolving “Stuck” Background Tasks

Tags: cache, tasks

Hi guys so I am having an issue with the "generating pending image transforms" being stuck.

I've seen the solution listed here https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks telling me to go to the craft_tasks table and fix the error. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get to this table. Where is it? No one seems to explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a GUI MySQL client to connect to the Craft database and edit the table directly.  Popular ones include [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) and [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), but there is a good list [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-MySQL-client-for-Mac-OS-X-or-Windows) of options for both OSX and Windows.

Once you connect to the database, you can edit the data in the `craft_tasks` table and change the value of `status` from `running` to `pending` to re-trigger it.

Comment: Thanks Heaps Brad, I was able to just go into phpMyAdmin and fix the stuck tasks. Once I knew how to get there all the previous explanations made sense.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an even more user friendly way of doing it, install the [Task Manager plugin by Bob Olde Hampsink](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/taskmanager), and you can do it from the Craft control panel.

Comment: Thanks to Brads comment I was able to find the way in through phpMyAdmin. But I will definitely install it and give it a go.